# how to throttle downloads in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, download, connection

I've got various downloads I'd like to get without impacting the rest of my office's connection speeds (we're on a pretty slow connection).

I was wondering if there was some way to easily add/remove download speed throttles within Chrome.

Comment: +1 How thoughtful to tamper your own performance for the good of others!

Comment: No, he just doesn't want to get caught.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Download Helper](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mfjkgbjaikamkkojmakjclmkianficch) with an external download manager that supports throttling.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this is apparently a windows only plug-in.

Comment: Should unflag this answer because this language is on the chrome addon installation page "We no longer provide this extension because most features were made in NPAPI and NPAPI is no longer supported in Chrome.". and this was the first hit on google "throttle chrome downloads"

Comment: are there any alternatives?

Answer (score -1):

Use the developer tools, network tab to enable throttling.

https://css-tricks.com/throttling-the-network/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.